# Tag object in map in Unreal

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, text

Is there a clean way in unreal to place text in the map to tag different buildings and areas for developper that can easily be turned on/off for all the tags in the map?

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the scale of your project. If it's small scale, you could create a custom component (that can be added to any actor) to display what you want. The downside is that this is per-actor so you cannot easily enable or disablw it for all actors in the scene. If your project is larger scale or you want reusability, I'd go with a custom editor plugin; however this is a serious rabbit-hole and can end up being more work than necessary.

Once you decide, I may be able to suggest more appropriate steps.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways that I can think of off the top of my head:

1. A parent blueprint for all placeable objects. Pros: everything behaves the same. Cons: some objects may need another parent class.
2. An editor plugin that adds a text component to all objects in a level. Pros: lots of control because it's an editor plugin, and it can bind directly to menus and toolbars. Cons: harder to write and may be overkill for what you want.

There may be other more appropriate options if we know a little nore about the intended functionality and usage.

Comment: something like what you can see at 1m45 in the intro videoof this course : https://www.udemy.com/unityrpg/

Comment: I was also thinking about putting all the anotation in an anotation layer that you can turn on/off, but i'm not sure if it's good practice.